# catch block not catching exception in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, try-catch

```
method A()
{
  try
  {
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(B));
    t.Start();
  }
  catch(exception e)
  {
    //show message of exception
  }      

}

method B()
{
 // getDBQuery
}
```

a exception in B but not catched.
does it legal in .net?

Comment: See answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5983779/395718) for ways to get exception from another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `A` is finished executing `B` might still be running as it is on an independent thread. For that reason it is *impossible by principle* for `A` to catch all exceptions that `B` produces.

Move the try-catch to inside of `B`. The `Thread` class does not forward exceptions.

Better yet, use `Task` which allows you to propagate and inspect exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

Correct, exceptions from a Thread are not forwarded to the caller, the Thread should handle this by itself.

The most general answer is that you should not be using a (bare) Thread here.  It's not efficient and not convenient.

When you use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), the exception is stored and raised when you cal `Wait()` or `Result`.