# Does an exception end a thread although it is try/catch?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two questions:

If I have a method like this:

```
public void DoMyWork()
{
   throw new MyException(anyString);
}
```

...and I call it `async` like this:

```
public void DoMyWorkAsync()
{
   try
   {
      new Thread(DoMyWork).Start();
   }

   catch (MyException)
   {
      // Do anything
   }
}
```

First of all, will the exception be caught with a try-block like this? And if so, will the thread be ended, because normally with an exception the thread stops, but if I catch it, will it end, too, or do I have to implement a `CancellationToken` then?

Comment: The problem is, it won't catch the exception, maybe it will and I am to dumb :D, so I thought to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, will the exception be catched with a try-block like
>   this?

No, it won't be caught.

You need to wrap the code inside `DoMyWork`  method with `try/catch` to catch that exception.

Note:It will result in "Unhandled exception", any unhandled exception will tear down the process(Application crash).

Comment: Ok thanks. So, I cannot just go ahead and put a try/catch around it, because the method should be used as normal, too and it should be free how you would handle the exceptions, that is the problem.

Comment: Only way is catch the exceptions in expected places, if you don't you'll be punished with "Application crash"

Comment: Ok, is there maybe an alternative? Like tasks? How far can I do it with them maybe?

Comment: @Trade Yes, Tasks are better alternatives. It will not crash your process if unhandled exception is thrown(in .net 4.5). You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/31/9674669.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!
I also found this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread

Is it possible to make the handler overridable, so that the user could implement his own way to handle the exeption?
Would that be a solution?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the `Action<Exception>` while creating task which you will store in `Task.State` property, then in `ExceptionHandler` method you will call the `action(task.Exception)` so that user will be able to pass thier own delegates which encapsulates custom error handling.

Answer (score 2):

1) No, it will not. Exceptions in threads must be dealt with in the thread. The main thread does not control the flow of execution of the thread, thus, does not capture the exception.

2) The application will terminate. More here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hm ok, I cannot just go ahead and put a try/catch around it, because the method should be used as normal, too and it should be free how you would handle the exceptions, that is the problem.