# TargetInvocationException in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to call method from another assembly in WinForm like this

```
private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
     {
         string assemblyPath = "PluginForSnake.dll";
         AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyNewDomain");
         ObjectHandle handle = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(assemblyPath, "PluginForSnake.Save");
         object obj = handle.Unwrap();
         MessageBox.Show("found");

         if (RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(obj)){
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            object[] param = new object[] { _snake, _food };
            MethodInfo saveGame = type.GetMethod("saveGame");
            saveGame.Invoke(obj, param);
         }
      });

      thread.IsBackground = true;
      thread.Start();
}
```

But im getting this exception at Invoke line

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: I didn´t write any.

Answer (score 1):

TargetInvocationException can be hell to figure out. There are a few ways to make it easier for you.

First, you can try to use `Task`, for better exception handling [1]

And/or, you can create a delegate[2] and call it as you would a function, instead of Invoking it. This will give you whatever exception is thrown by the `saveGame` function instead of "the invoke failed". The process of creating the delegate can also reveal other issues with the function you are trying to Invoke, and is a great learning excercise.

[1] [catch exception that is thrown in different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread)

[2] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx