# Thread started from a thread in C# doesnot raise unhandled expection args

Tags: c#, .net

if you run this code below, the event handler is never invoked for global error handler.

```
static bool exiting = false;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        System.Threading.Thread demo = new System.Threading.Thread(DemoThread);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        demo.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        exiting = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught an exception");
    }
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Notified of a thread exception... application is terminating.");
}

static void DemoThread()
{
    Action x = () => { throw new Exception("this is simple"); };
    x.BeginInvoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: try to look at this example it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `BeginInvoke()`.

If you used `x();` you wouldn't have a problem.

Put simply, if you call a delegate using  `BeginInvoke()`, any exception that is thrown during its execution is handled and then rethrown when you call `EndInvoke()` however you are using this as a fire and forget (I'm not sure why), and your exception is unobserved as it has nothing to call back to.

Solve?

```
x.EndInvoke(x.BeginInvoke(null, null));

// or

x();
```

The call to `EndInvoke` raises the exception on the caller, and it propagates to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` as you would expect.

However on saying this, this all seems a little suspicious, I think you should ditch trying to call a delegate asynchronously and the `Thread` class in general, and use tasks and appropriate modern BCL methods and patterns for asynchrony.,

---

**Additional Resources**

[Delegate Class](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> If an invoked method throws an exception, the method stops executing,
> the exception is passed back to the caller of the delegate, and
> remaining methods in the invocation list are not invoked. Catching the
> exception in the caller does not alter this behavior.

For documentation Asynchronous patterns and delegates:

[Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously)