# How to catch unhandled errors in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I've created a simple MVC project, add one method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<string> Index()
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Debug.Print("Debug___1");
            throw new Exception("Error #1");
            Debug.Print("Debug___2");
        });
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return "ASD";
    }
}
```

Then i run application, get "ASD" output and debug messages:

```
Debug___1
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in WebApplication2.dll
```

But how can I catch that exception? I've tried creating Application_Error method on global.asas, but it didn't work:

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("Catched");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to catch Exceptions arising from Task.Run?

Comment: @mahlatse Kind of, without using await.

Comment: Have you tried [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)

Answer (score 0):

At the controller level, you can deal with unhandled exceptions by overriding the OnException method.

Look at this link for a description: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine

Comment: Doesn't work exceptions in Task.Run(). But works for other exception in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
 //create custom error handling method
 ErrorLog(ex);
}

Public static void Errorlog(Exception ex)
{
//creates new txt file to view errordetails
 string strPath = @"D:\ErrorLog.txt";
 File.create(strPath);
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
 {
   sw.WriteLine("Error Details",+DateTime.Now);
   sw.WriteLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
   sw.WriteLine("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4 allows you to define how your task will handle exceptions as shown in the following post : [catch exception that is thrown in different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread)

So in your example above, you would first define your task

```
Task<string> task = new Task<string>(Test);
```

then pass in an exception handler

```
task.ContinueWith(ExceptionHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

then finally define an exception handler somewhere

```
static void ExceptionHandler(Task<string> task)
{
    var exception = task.Exception;
    //Handle error via ModelState or how you prefer 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the HttpServerUtility.HttpApplication.Server object's method GetLastError.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
}
```