# Application breaks on re-throw Exception Fody

Tags: c#, async-await, fody

I am trying to handle all the exceptions thrown from a async method,
but when i throw the exception after the execution of an async child method,then on re-throw exception from fody(OnException method) application breaks.

Like:

```
using MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody.Attributes;

public sealed class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        //re-throw exception
        throw args.Exception;
    }
}

public class ClassName
{
    [ExceptionHandler]
    public async Task<T> MethodAsync()
    {
        //do some async work
        await OtherClass.DoSomeWorkAsync();
        throw new Exception("Exception after the execution of an Async method");
    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
    public async Task<T> MethodAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            ClassName className=new ClassName();
            await className.MethodAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the application break?

Comment: @PauloMorgado execute the above code in a WEB application.

Comment: So, who is catching the exception, or who do you expect to catch it? Are you sure that `OnException` should re-throw?

Comment: @Andrew i have just added some more detail in code kindly recheck it.

Comment: Just run it outside the debugger. Then it won't break.

Comment: I'd say it's not catching it because it's in a separate thread. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread). Still, are you supposed to throw an exception in `OnException`? I think that method is supposed to handle errors, not produce them.

Comment: @Andrew I know the method is used to handle exceptions but in my application it is used to catch and re-throw exception in some cases like if the exception is not a custom exception then log and throw a custom exception.

Comment: @StephenCleary I have tried it "outside the debugger" but the application still breaks.

Comment: Maybe it's something to Fody-specific. Could this work inside `OnException`? `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(args.Exception).Throw();` I found it in [this discussion](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody/issues/5).